# Android AsyncTask, данные передаются позже чем надо

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, rest

Пишу *REST* клиент, но столкнулся с проблемой.

Из главной активности у меня вызывается метод `connect()` класа `Api`, который должен возвращать стринг, полученный по *GET* через *AsyncTask*. Дело в том, что использую глобальный стринг, который должен присваиваться в методе `onPostExecute(String result)` и возвращаться методом `connect()`. Ну и `onPostExecute()` выполняется позже, чем метод `connect()` передает значение, то есть возвращаются не данные, а `null`.

Во второй итерации действий передается уже `String`, который был сгенерирован на предыдущей итерации и т.д. Как это решить? Я где-то допустил ошибку?

Вызываю из главной активности:

```
data = api.connect(apiKey,"","&page="+pageNumber+"&sort="+sortingMode);
```

Класс Api:

```
public class Api extends  MainActivity{
static String responeData;
static String uri;
static String getUrl = "http://....?";
static String searchUrl ="http://f....?";

//Generate links
public static String generateGetUri(String key, String recipeId){
    return uri = getUrl+"key="+key+"&"+recipeId;
}
public static String generateSearchUri(String key, String userRequest,String params){
    return searchUrl+"key="+key+userRequest+params;
}

public static String connect(String key, String userRequest,String params){
    uri = generateSearchUri(key,userRequest,params);
    new HttpAsyncTask().execute(uri);
    return responeData;
}
public static void connect(String key, String recipeId){
    generateGetUri(key, recipeId);
    new HttpAsyncTask().execute(uri);
}

public static String GET(String url){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        if(inputStream != null) {
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        }
        else
            result = "Did not work!";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return result;
}

private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    String s;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line;
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;
    inputStream.close();      
    return result;
}
private static class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return GET(urls[0]);
    }
   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
       responeData = result; //исполняется позже, чем метод connect передаст responeData;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Вам стоит почитать что-нить по синхронным и асинхронным вызовам в программировании. Потому что ваша проблема сейчас -- это только вершина айсберга. Этот код надо весь переписывать.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja знаю что все очень плохо, но только учусь. Обязательно прочитаю об этом.

Comment: стремления к знаниям вознаграждаются :)

Answer (score 1):

Разумеется onPostExecute выполнится позже, чем метод connect() вернет значение, т.к. AsynkTask создаст под свои нужды отдельный поток. В doItBackground выполняется код, заключенынй в try-catch, который априори будет выполняться дольше, чем код в главном потоке, в котором продолжит свою работу метод connect(). Установка каких-либо значений должна происходить прямо в методе onPostExecute()

Кстати, у AsynkTask есть метод get(), который вернет значение, полученное в doInBackgorund и даже дождется его завершения!

Comment: Так можно и свой метод `public static String GET(String url)` напрямую вызвать, зачем `AsynkTask` с `get()` тогда?

Comment: Какой смысл запускать ```AsyncTask```, а потом блокировать UI поток вызовом ```get()```?

Answer (score 1):

Немного погуглив решил проблему так:
вызываю теперь так:

```
 api.connect(apiKey,"","&page="+pageNumber+"&sort="+sortingMode);
```

Метод в классе Api:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
       MainActivity.reciveData(result);
    }
```

А в классе главной активности создал метод, который будет принимать данное значение и уже вызывать нужные методы:

```
public static void reciveData (String str){      
    data = str;
    //дальше работаем с данными
}
```

Comment: Это называется `callback`, только по уму его нельзя делать статическим, в случае нескольких вызовов одновременно, у вас результат будет непредсказуемым.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте interface или Broadcast для уведомления вашей Activity об окончании загрузки и передачи данных из onPostExecute